# Classify text from words array

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm trying to classify texts in dataframe through the list of words in the array. if the word is found then the next column would get populated with that word otherwise none should be given

Code so far:

```
Product=['Fish','food','Product','Expensive','cheap','expensive','seafood','ice cream','delicious','taste','smell','selection','price','grilled']
df=pd_read_csv("text.csv")
df['classify']=""
for i in range(len(df)): 
  paragraph=df[i]
  count = Counter(paragraph.split())

  pos = 0
  for key, val in count.items():
    key = key.rstrip('.,?!\n') # removing possible punctuation signs
    if key in positive:
       df['classify'][i]=key
```

Desired Results:

```
Text                               Classify
"The food is bad"                  food
"He parked the car"                none
```

Any Help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
import pandas as pd
Product=['Fish','food','Product','Expensive','cheap','expensive','seafood','ice cream','delicious','taste','smell','selection','price','grilled']
df=pd.DataFrame({'Text':["The food is bad", "He parked the car"]})

def classify(text):
    for i in Product:
        if i in ''.join(text.values).split():
            return i
    return None

df['classify']=df.apply(classify, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
                Text classify
0    The food is bad     food
1  He parked the car     None
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create function like:

```
def classify(classification_list, text, data_id):
    for check_word in classification_list:
        if check_word.lower() in text.lower():
            df['classify'][data_id] = check_word
            break
        else:
            df['classify'][data_id] = None
```

And usage:

```
products=['Fish','food','Product','Expensive','cheap','expensive','seafood','ice cream','delicious','taste','smell','selection','price','grilled']

for data_id in range(0, len(df)):
    classify(products, df['text'][data_id], data_id)
```

Finally you will get the DataFrame like this:

```
>>> df
                text classify
0    The food is bad     food
1  He parked the car     None
```